# Cluster analysis in R with images instead of labels

Tags: r, image, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I am running a cluster analysis in R and I would like to show images (stored in a folder with numbers for filenames) in the tree rather than labels.

Any suggestions on how to modify the code so that I can use images rather than labels in the graph for the tree?